# web api, routing issue with my post method

Tags: c#, web-services, angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an issue with my web api controler routing. I've made GET methods that works fine, but now, I try some POST and routing seems to be bad.
I've have a front and with Angular2. Here, you can see the call to webapi :

```
 retour = this._http.post("http://localhost:5000/api/Particulier/add", _particulier, options)
        .map(postResult)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Here it's my web api method :

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/")]
public class ParticulierController : Controller
{

    [...]

    [HttpPost("add")]
    public async Task<bool> Add([FromBody]Particulier particulier)
    {
        var result = await _particulierService.Create(particulier);
        return result;
    }

    [...]

}
```

it's simple, but doesn't work. Chrome say me that the url doesn't exist. I have GET methods in the same controller and they works.

can you help me ?

thanks,

Comment: Doesn't work is not much to go on. Are there any exceptions. what is the status code that is returned from the request?

Comment: Confirm what version of asp.net you are using. The code you posted is for `asp.net-core` but you tagged your post with `asp.net-web-api`.

Comment: It's an ASP.net Core Web Application (.net Core) with the Web API template. framework 4.6.1.

Comment: I have no request shown in chrome console (network tab) when I submit the request. The issue is probably with the Agular2 http service. but no error

Answer (score 0):

The method `Add([FromBody]Particulier particulier)` may not be matching your request because there are missing non-nullable properties specified for the `Particulier` parameter. Or, it could be an issue with deserializing the request.

I recommend trying it with the `Content-Type: text/json` header if it's not an issue with missing properties.

```
retour = this._http({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/Particulier/add',
        method: "POST",
        data: _particulier,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // map post result (data var)
});
```

Comment: I'm using application/json but with text/json that doesn't work better. but it's normal if my Typescript object must completly match C# object. my C# Particulier and my TS Particulier have some identical parameters, but not all.. did you think it's the problem ?

Comment: Can you look at the request though something like Chrome dev tools? It shouldn't be an issue unless TS Particulier object is missing non-nullable property types like `int`, `DateTime` that are defined in `Particulier`

Comment: I've try a simple action. My controller want a string parameter call "test" and I POST a simple object like this : {"test":"toto"}. But the controller isn't called. I don't understand. It"s the first time I use Web API, but when I made post request with Jquery in an MVC application i've no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's resolved. The request is not executed until the Angular service is not subsribed.

thanks to everyone